# :not does not work for animation on uncheck

Tags: html, css

I create a little toggle switch. I use a hidden checkbox and the following CSS

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div {
  animation-name: slide;
  animation-duration: 350ms;
  margin-left: 32px;
}
```

and HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
<div class="knob">
  <div class="knob inside"> | </div>
</div>
```

Complete codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZKyzK

And it is clear that the following can not work:

```
input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked) ~ div {
  animation-name: slide;
  animation-duration: 350ms;
  animation-direction: reverse;
  margin-left: 32px;
}
```

because the entry state is of course `:not(:checked)`. But I don't want the animation to start then. The second problem is that the animation will play only once. Is there a way to achieve the switch behavior:
1. skip first animation
2. play animation each time the status of the checkbox changes and not only once

Comment: Are you okay with using javascript/jQuery solution to solve this?

Comment: unfortunately not. not using js was the point.

Answer (score 1):

2. play animation each time the status of the checkbox changes

Added a new animation for reversing. it did work.

```
@keyframes slideBack {
    from {
      margin-left: 32px;
    }
    to {
      margin-left: 0px;
    }
}
```

Also in the codepen link you shared please change this,

```
input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked) ~ div {
  animation-name: slideBack;
  animation-duration: 350ms;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```